# cxf parameter optimaization

Tags: wsdl, cxf, endpoint

in cxf web service my request is

```
<student>
    <name>jaleel</name>
     <age>26</age>
</student>
```

here i want get age as optional

how it is possible;

i am using spring java in cxf.

my end point is

```
<bean id="tsetService" class="com.maxartists.tsm.server.TestServiceImpl"></bean>

<jaxws:endpoint id="issure_password_request" 
                     address="/testserver">    
                    <jaxws:implementor>
                            <bean parent="tsetService" />
                    </jaxws:implementor>
     </jaxws:endpoint>
```

My web service method is

```
@WebService
public interface TestService {
@WebMethod
    public String test( Testvo type);
    @WebMethod
    public Result validation(@WebParam(name="pwvalue") Studentvo ipvo);
```

This is my parameter type

public class Studentvo {
    String name;
  int age;

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name= name;
}
```

public void setAge(int age){

```
 this.age = age;
```

}

public int getAge(){
   retrun age;
 }

Answer (score 0):

If you change the "type" of age from "int" to Integer, it would automatically be made optional.

Alternatively, you could add an @XmlElement(required="false") attribute to the getter/setter/field and that should also make it optional.